# Visitor Pattern in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I've been looking at the best way to implement the Visitor design pattern in Objective-C. Since the language doesn't support method overloading, a 'traditional' implementation such as one might find in Java seems impossible.

In my current implementation, I have a Visitor protocol, a Visitor class, and several subclasses of that Visitor class, along with the various objects to visit. Once a visited object accepts the Visitor, they call the visit method of the Visitor, passing themselves as an argument. The visit method takes an id, then type-casts it and calls

```
[self performTasksOnObjectClass: (ObjectClass *)object];
```

as part of an if/elseif/else block. These calls are them picked up by the relevant Visitor subclass and the Visitor performs whatever tasks it needs to on the object.

Is there a better way of implementing the Visitor pattern than this? I dislike resorting to 'isKindOfClass' or 'isMemberOfClass' calls inside if/elseif/else blocks. It just seems clunky and inelegant. Additionally, is it still 'worth' implementing a Visitor method in this way? The visited objects can still remain ignorant of the Visitor, but there are other ways in which this can be achieved.

It has already been suggested that either delegation or class clusters might be more suitable alternatives to the Visitor pattern. I'd be interested to see what you all think!

Edit: I actually had differently named methods being called in the subclass, I've made this clearer.

Comment: Regardless with the design pattern you end up choosing, I would definitely read through Apple's documentation on Cocoa Design Patterns. You may find a pattern that is more suited to your needs. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html

Comment: Thanks for the link Reed - but I am really interested in an elegant solution for Visitor, especially as it works so nicely in conjunction with Composite.

Comment: I am reading Carlo Chung's Pro Objective-C design Patterns, I recommend it. http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Objective-C-Design-Patterns-iOS/dp/1430233303. He implemented the Visitor pattern in the book much like you did with a protocol and then passing -(void)acceptMarkVisitor:(id <MarkVisitor>) visitor. He notes (paraphrased) that a notable drawback of the visitor patterns in Objective-C is that  a visitor is coupled with the target class. Also adding new nodes involves changing the protocol. He suggests having a catch all visitObj:(id) obj in the protocol for future changes.

Comment: @RickiG unfortunately the Apress webs site for the book *doesn't* contain chapter 15 - the one of the Visitor Design pattern!

Comment: Ahh I see that now.You can download the source files for the book - in the TouchPainter project, which is the big project he makes that encompasses all the patterns, there is a MarkVisitor.h protocol and you can investigate from there. http://www.apress.com/9781430233305 (hope it is ok to link directly to the source, it is publicly available).

Comment: @RickiG  You probably should change your comment into an answer, even though it is suggesting what the OP is already doing.

Comment: discussion here: http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184410252, related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334731/objective-c-categories-visitor-pattern, discussion: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?VisitorPattern

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use some introspection/reflection to make this a bit cleaner. You can't overload method names but you can avoid writing a switch statement like this:

```
- (void)performTasks:(id)object
{
    Class class = [object class];
    while (class && class != [NSObject class])
    {
        NSString *methodName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"perform%@Tasks:", class];
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);
        if ([self respondsToSelector:selector])
        {
            [self performSelector:selector withObject:object];
            return;
        }
        class = [class superclass];
    }
    [NSException raise:@"Visitor %@ doesn't have a performTasks method for %@", [self class], [object class]];
}
```

Your actual performTasks methods would then be named as follows:

```
- (void)performFooTasks:(Foo *)foo
{
    //tasks for objects of class Foo
}

- (void)performBarTasks:(Bar *)bar
{
    //tasks for objects of class Bar
}

etc...
```

**Note:** If you're using ARC, you'll get spurious warnings by creating selectors from strings in this way because it can't tell at compile time what the retain rules should be for the method parameters. You can silence these warnings using a #pragma, as follows:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [self performSelector:selector withObject:object];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: I like that, and it would save altering the method when adding new visited object types. I'd add a check for whether self performs the selector to avoid potential runtime errors, but I take it that would result in yet more warnings! I'll have a look at objc/message.h tomorrow when I'm properly awake, I'm sure there'll be a similar equivalent to hush up the warnings there too. Thank you, this could well be the answer I've been looking for :)

Comment: You don't get a warning for using if respondsToSelector. The warning is because ARC isn't sure whether to retain "object" when you pass it to your selector because it doesn't know what the selector is at compile time since it's constructed at runtime, which isn't a problem if you're just checking to see if the method exists. I'm not actually 100% sure you'll get the warning if the method has no return value.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it will correctly handle objects subclasses. The nice thing with this solution is that if you visit a Dog which is a subclass of Animal, you can have either a performDogTasks or a performAnimalTasks method (or both) and it will use the more selective method depending on the object passed in. That sort of thing is hard to do even in languages with method overloading because they can't determine which subclass a parameter is at compile time.

Comment: I've had chance to have a look at this properly now. This really is just what i was after, a great answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

You could take the following approach to map selectors to objc types, and then let this implementation do the method lookups for the "dynamic overloading". Such an implementation would remove the majority of the noise for your actual uses (see Demo -- 8 pages down):

Our includes:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

## Our basic types:

**MONVisitorEntry** associates a Class to a selector:

MONVisitorEntry.h:

```
@interface MONVisitorEntry : NSObject

+ (MONVisitorEntry *)newVisitorEntryWithType:(Class)inType selector:(SEL)inSelector;

- (id)visit:(id)target parameter:(id)parameter;

- (Class)type;

@end
```

MONVisitorEntry.m:

```
@implementation MONVisitorEntry
{
@private
  Class type;
  SEL selector;
}

- (id)initWithType:(Class)inType selector:(SEL)inSelector
{
  self = [super init];
  if (0 != self) {
    type = inType;
    selector = inSelector;
  }
  return self;
}

- (NSString *)description
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - Type: %@ - SEL: %@", [super description], type, NSStringFromSelector(selector)];
}

- (NSUInteger)hash
{
  return (NSUInteger)type;
}

- (Class)type
{
  return type;
}

+ (MONVisitorEntry *)newVisitorEntryWithType:(Class)inType selector:(SEL)inSelector
{
  return [[self alloc] initWithType:inType selector:inSelector];
}

- (id)visit:(id)target parameter:(id)parameter
{
  return ([target methodForSelector:selector])(target, selector, parameter);
}

@end
```

**MONVisitorMap** is a map of `MONVisitorEntry` objects. this type has no type safety -- you should reintroduce it.

MONVisitorMap.h:

```
@interface MONVisitorMap : NSObject

- (void)addEntryWithType:(Class)inType selector:(SEL)inSelector;

/* perhaps you would prefer that inTarget is also held by self? in that case, you could also cache the IMPs for faster lookups. */
- (id)visit:(id)inTarget parameter:(id)inParameter;

@end
```

MONVisitorMap.m:

```
@implementation MONVisitorMap
{
@private
  NSMutableSet * entries;
}

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (0 != self) {
    entries = [NSMutableSet new];
  }
  return self;
}

- (NSString *)description
{
  return [[super description] stringByAppendingString:[entries description]];
}

- (void)addEntryWithType:(Class)inType selector:(SEL)inSelector
{
  [entries addObject:[MONVisitorEntry newVisitorEntryWithType:inType selector:inSelector]];
}

- (id)visit:(id)inTarget parameter:(id)inParameter parameterClass:(Class)inParameterClass
{
  MONVisitorEntry * entry = 0;
  for (MONVisitorEntry * at in entries) {
    if (inParameterClass == at.type) {
      entry = at;
    }
  }

  if (0 != entry) {
    return [entry visit:inTarget parameter:inParameter];
  }

  Class superclass = class_getSuperclass(inParameterClass);
  if (0 == superclass) {
    assert(0 && "exhausted class hierarchy!");
    return 0;
  }

  return [self visit:inTarget parameter:inParameter parameterClass:superclass];
}

- (id)visit:(id)inTarget parameter:(id)inParameter
{
  return [self visit:inTarget parameter:inParameter parameterClass:[inParameter class]];
}

@end
```

## Demo:

**Create some test types (add some `.m` files here):**

```
@interface Animal : NSObject
@end
@implementation Animal
@end

@interface Dog : Animal
@end
@implementation Dog
@end

@interface Greyhound : Dog
@end
@implementation Greyhound
@end

@interface Boxer : Dog
@end
@implementation Boxer
@end

@interface Squirrel : Animal
@end
@implementation Squirrel
@end

@interface Tapir : Animal
@end
@implementation Tapir
@end
```

**Create the visitor:**

MONZoo.h:

```
@interface MONZoo : NSObject
/* our abstract "visit" entry, which introduces type safety: */
- (void)exhibit:(Animal *)inAnimal;
@end
```

MONZoo.m:

```
@implementation MONZoo
{
@private
  MONVisitorMap * visitorMap;
}

static NSString * Message(NSString * inMessage, id inInstance) {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message: \"%@\" -- Instance: %@", inMessage, inInstance];
}

// Here's where you implement a method for an animal:
- (id)visitAnimal:(Animal *)p { return Message(@"What animal is this?", p); }
- (id)visitDog:(Dog *)p { return Message(@"What's up, Dog!", p); }
- (id)visitGreyhound:(Greyhound *)p { return Message(@"Ohhhhh a Greyhound!!", p); }
- (id)visitTapir:(Tapir *)p { return Message(@"What does it cost to feed this?", p); }

// Here's where you map methods to animals:    
+ (MONVisitorMap *)newVisitorMap
{
  MONVisitorMap * map = [MONVisitorMap new];

  [map addEntryWithType:[Dog class] selector:@selector(visitDog:)];
  [map addEntryWithType:[Greyhound class] selector:@selector(visitGreyhound:)];
  [map addEntryWithType:[Tapir class] selector:@selector(visitTapir:)];
  [map addEntryWithType:[Animal class] selector:@selector(visitAnimal:)];
  /* omitting the Boxer (Dog) to demonstrate pseudo-overload */

  return map;
}

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (0 != self) {
    visitorMap = [[self class] newVisitorMap];
  }
  return self;
}

- (NSString *)description
{
  return [[super description] stringByAppendingString:[visitorMap description]];
}

- (void)exhibit:(Animal *)inAnimal
{
  NSLog(@"Visiting Exhibit: %@", [visitorMap visit:self parameter:inAnimal]);
}

@end
```

**Now try it out:**

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  @autoreleasepool {
    MONZoo * zoo = [MONZoo new];

    NSLog(@"Hello, Zoo! -- %@", zoo);

    [zoo exhibit:[Dog new]];
    [zoo exhibit:[Greyhound new]];
    [zoo exhibit:[Squirrel new]];
    [zoo exhibit:[Tapir new]];
    [zoo exhibit:[Boxer new]];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Which yields our trip to the zoo:**

```
2012-02-21 04:38:58.360 Visitor[2195:403] Hello, Zoo! -- <MONZoo: 0x10440ed80><MONVisitorMap: 0x1044143f0>{(
    <MONVisitorEntry: 0x104414e00> - Type: Dog - SEL: visitDog:,
    <MONVisitorEntry: 0x104410840> - Type: Greyhound - SEL: visitGreyhound:,
    <MONVisitorEntry: 0x104415150> - Type: Animal - SEL: visitAnimal:,
    <MONVisitorEntry: 0x104415130> - Type: Tapir - SEL: visitTapir:
)}
2012-02-21 04:38:58.363 Visitor[2195:403] Visiting Exhibit: Message: "What's up, Dog!" -- Instance: <Dog: 0x7f9a29d00120>
2012-02-21 04:38:58.363 Visitor[2195:403] Visiting Exhibit: Message: "Ohhhhh a Greyhound!!" -- Instance: <Greyhound: 0x7f9a29e002c0>
2012-02-21 04:38:58.364 Visitor[2195:403] Visiting Exhibit: Message: "What animal is this?" -- Instance: <Squirrel: 0x104416470>
2012-02-21 04:38:58.364 Visitor[2195:403] Visiting Exhibit: Message: "What does it cost to feed this?" -- Instance: <Tapir: 0x7f9a29d00120>
2012-02-21 04:38:58.364 Visitor[2195:403] Visiting Exhibit: Message: "What's up, Dog!" -- Instance: <Boxer: 0x1044140a0>
```

**Notes:**

- Bring your own error detection ;)
- Excuse the quick write up
- Excuse the lack of docs
- Compiled with ARC
- Of course, there are variations you can make to suit your needs.
- This may not be the truest form of the pattern, but you can easily introduce that by adding one or two methods using this program, if that is the approach you favor.

Comment: That's similar to my solution, but the advantage of generating the method names using reflection is that you don't have to manually maintain a map of class names->visitor methods as you've done here. Coding by naming convention can lead to some very elegant, DRY solutions, which is why Apple use it so heavily within Cocoa (KVC uses it to determine setter/getter names, UIViewController uses the class name to select the nib automatically, ARC uses it to determine if a method returns an autoreleased object, etc.).

Comment: @NickLockwood The only part that's really similar is the class hierarchy traversal (a technique you added to your answer after it existed in my answer). The map (my answer) will lookup faster than string building (your answer), it is more easily extended, specialized, and mutated. The map scales better, and is more flexible. String building can also be tedious to maintain in larger systems. However, the simplicity of string building can be good for small problems. The map could also be easily adapted to support `SEL` name matching, if desired -- just construct it using an array of `Class`es.

Comment: I meant that it was similar in that both solutions provide a way to automatically map a generic function "visitObject" to a specific one "visitTapir". I very much disagree with the approach of building complex, manual solutions to problems that can be solved with simple DRY solutions on the basis of hypothetical extensibility, and I would argue that optimising development time is generally a better goal than trying to optimise runtime performance, except for very specialist cases (inner loops of graphics routines, etc), but I suspect we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Apologies if it seemed like I stole your class traversal idea without giving due credit. I'll admit that your answer did make me realise that I should add such a feature, but I hope you'll recognise that I didn't use any of your code, or duplicate your algorithm.

Comment: @NickLockwood i don't mind chatting or discussing answers with you -- but the bible banging is annoying =) could you keep it to your answer in the future? tia.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't see a lot of substance in your comments beyond: You believe my solution is inferior (your opinion), you find my solution objectionable (your opinion), it would not please the hardcore XP or whichever camp (your methodology), and a list of cliches (heard 'em!). If you want to promote your methodology, let your answer be a forum for that. I find it rude to make my answer a forum for that -- it wastes my time and detracts from the answer. Without substance, I can't really sustain a conversation. I'll speak my mind, but don't let that lead you to believe I dislike you. Cheers.

Comment: @NickLockwood FWIW, I don't mind that you updated your answer based on my technique. Personally, I would have given credit in the answer. This is a place for learning and sharing -- not a patent office ;)

Comment: `([target methodForSelector:selector])(target, selector, parameter)` why not just `[target performSelector:selector withObject:parameter]`?